# How to align this block of text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have a problem. How can I put this text perfectly aligned on the right side, like the trying of the screenshot?

[image: Screenshot #1]

Is there a smarter way?

```
\noindent 
\hspace*{8cm}
Artigo apresentado ao curso de graduação em\\
\hspace*{8cm}
Engenharia Civil da Universidade Católica de\\
\hspace*{8cm}
 Brasília, como requerimento parcial para a\\
\hspace*{8cm}
obtenção do Título de Bacharel em Engenharia\\ 
\hspace*{8cm}
Civil.
```

Comment: Place it in a `minipage` using `\raggedright` inside and an `\hfill` in front of the minipage.

Comment: @Johannes_B I was typing my answer while you posted your comment, which is essentially identical. I have changed the authorship of my answer as "community wiki". Hope this is alright for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested in the comment by @Johannes_B you could wrap the text into a minipage and use `\hfill` before the definition of the minipage, in order to place it on the right side of the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for the rendering of accented characters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\raggedright % obviates the need for explicit linebreaks
Artigo apresentado ao curso de graduação em
Engenharia Civil da Universidade Católica de
Brasília, como requerimento parcial para a
obtenção do Título de Bacharel em Engenharia
Civil.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost identical to the example i had ready :-)

Comment: It worked! Thank you @Johannes_B and RHertel !!

Comment: @PedroFelipeOliveira, if answer worked for you, why then you didn't accept it?